# Simple way to post score from my game to Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: c++, android, facebook, cocos2d-x, twitter

What's the best and simple way to post score from my game to Facebook and Twitter with store link in cocos2d-x?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best way, but both FB and twitter provided API for these actions. you can open a TCP connection to their server and send a request based on their API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter has a [developer portal](https://dev.twitter.com/), where you'll probably want to check out the REST API. Specifically the [POST statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) endpoint. Because this API is HTTP-based, you'll need a way to make such requests from your game. [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c) addresses that subject, with suggestions such as [curlpp](http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/).

Facebook has a similar set of APIs available, described on [their developer portal](http://developers.facebook.com/). Unfortunately most of their actual documentation is behind a Facebook login wall, so I won't link it directly. But if you search for ["facebook api post to wall"](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=facebook+api+post+to+wall) you get several results, including direct links to the graph API documentation for posting and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724977/using-facebook-graph-to-simply-post-a-wall-message-with-just-javascript).

Facebook has JavaScript, Objective-C and Java-based APIs.