# How to post player´s score on Facebook (with js)

Tags: javascript, facebook, phaser

I have my game made with Phaser (and compiled with cocoon.io) and on the leadersboard state I want to let the user to post his score on Facebook.

Well, I created an App on Facebook and I´m not finding a good solution to create this simple post, something like "I scored 10 points on this riduculous game..." Pretty easy on Twitter and not so easy on Facebook, I can find information about posting links and that stuff but I´m not finding a proper way to create a simple post just with text.

How do you guys do this? I guess I´m missing something, it shouldn´t be so complicated.

(I already tested this link and it´s not working for me [Simple way to post score from my game to Facebook and Twitter?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28841/simple-way-to-post-score-from-my-game-to-facebook-and-twitter) API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.)

Comment: Are you using Facebook's Graph API?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: I was, but it really sucks, so at the end I just linked to a webpage with a window.open.

Comment: If you're using Facebook, be aware of the following: https://stallman.org/facebook.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need to setup Facebook JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5

I have tried with open graph.

```
FB.ui({
 method: 'share_open_graph',
 action_type: 'namespace:action_type',
 action_properties: JSON.stringify({
     object_type:
      {
          'og:type': 'namespace:object_type',
          'og:title': 'I scored 10 points on this ridiculous game...',
          'og:image': 'http://www.bizreport.com/2011/02/03/android-logo-200x200.jpg',
          'og:description': 'Description'
      }
 })
}, function(response)
{
        if (response.post_id != null)
        {
            // handle response
        }
});
```

action_type and object_type are from Facebook application which I am sure you're familiar with.
And you'll need to submit the application for review if you're using custom stories.

Since I plan on using standard share dialog with custom image, text and link, I didn't spend much time figuring out open graph and how to set it up.

```
FB.ui({ method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://mysite.com/link-to-my-game',
    picture: 'http://www.bizreport.com/2011/02/03/android-logo-200x200.jpg',
    name: 'I scored 10 points on this ridiculous game...',
    description: 'Description',
    actions: [
        { name: 'Name of my site', link: 'http://mysite.com/' }
    ],
    display: 'popup'
  }, function (response)
  {
    if (response && response.post_id)
    {
        // handle response
    }
  });
```

Here you can see other parameters you may need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5

With this approach, sharing works as soon as you make your application public.
I need something simpler and I didn't want to submit the application for review, so I went with second option, but the first option is more powerful in terms of customizing.

About that redirect_uri error, I think it is because that redirect_uri domain is not listed in App Domains on your Facebook application Settings page. (correct me if I am wrong)

I am no expert at this, I just spent some time searching what I need, collected the code and played with it.

Comment: Still not working... I´m getting this error: Warning
Action type namespace:action_type is invalid

Comment: But the second approach is working fine, that was exactly what I wanted to do... thanks, mate.

Comment: You're welcome! action_type and object_type you need to replace with your actual action and object type from your application on Facebook. 
You can read more about that here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started, but there's more work involved to set it up than second approach.